# Becoming a CISO (Chief Information Security Officer) at a Startup. What would you ask future employer about?

Tags: job-search, resume, applications, leadership

What would you ask your potential employer/startup BEFORE becoming a CISO by them?

I can think of:

1. What is the current security strategy?
2. Who this role reports to?
3. What is the organization structure in regards to security? Who will
   implement all the trainings, hardenings, improvements and processes
4. Is this first time CISO role in the company?

Anything else? Anything will help.

How to present self in the best light. I am thinking about selling them my vision, approach and hopefully it matches their.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this is their first time? So consider how you would explain your approach - what you will need etc

Comment: Here comes another question; does a startup *need* a dedicated CISO? Titles like ''CEO'' are poorly used because CEO means ''Chief Executive Officer'', and as such being a chief big officer of 4 people means nothing. CISO is similar; the chief of information security... do they even need one person in that role, let alone a team under the chief?

Comment: As a cybersecurity professional, I definitely feel this question is not opinion based and answerable. Voting to reopen